# Did other British colonies at the time have seats in parliament

Tags: united-states, british-empire, colonial-america, american-revolution

I know the American colonies didn’t have a seat, but what about the other British colonies. Did some have it. Like Australia, and the places in Africa.

Comment: No - and "at the time" raises an issue: the *First Fleet* settlement of Australia was in 1783 after the loss of the 13 American colonies